# Python - how to randomly remove an item from the list until list is empty using both a while-loop and for-loop

Tags: python, list, loops, methods

I have been trying to remove a random item from a list using a while-loop and for-loop. For the while-loop, it should print it to the console until the list -days- is empty.

Here is my code thus far-

while-loop:

```
days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']

while len(days) > 0:
    days = days.pop(0)
```

for-loop:

```
for day in range(len(days)):
    day = days.pop(0)
```

output: for-loop:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

I am a novice programmer and I am struggling to correct this issue. Is there a way to pop items from the while loop? Can someone explain the attribute error and why I am getting this message?

Comment: This is a simple typo: your second example assigns to `day` instead of `days`.

Comment: In the future, please be clear in your description: "any feedback" is far to general -- ask a specific question.  Also, learn to trace your variable values, so you don't need to ask us to trace a typo for you.

Comment: There's nothing random about your code. It's strictly deterministic.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. My intention was to seek clarification on how to remove an element from list randomly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to remove randomly

```py
days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']

from random import randrange
while len(days) > 0:
    index=randrange(0,len(days))
    days.pop(index)
    print(days)

print('End')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop is the right way to do it. but you are overwriting the list with the first element.  You want

```
while days:
    day = days.pop(0)
```

The `for` loop is not good practice.  It is dangerous to modify a list while you are iterating through it.  Think about it.  First time through the loop, "day" is 0.  You pop element 0.  Now, the element that used to be [1] is in the [0] slot, but when you loop again, `day` will be 1 and your numbering is off.

And AGAIN, you are overwriting the loop variable (`day`) with the result of the pop.  Be careful with your variable names.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

To remove randomly you can use numpy to generate a random number, and then use .pop() to remove an item from the list and print it at the same time:

```
import numpy as np
days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']

while days:
    index = int(np.round((np.random.rand(1)-0.5)*len(days)))
    print(days.pop(index))
```